# Performance Navigation Type have same values in Refresh or Close

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, page-refresh, onbeforeunload

I'm trying identify the browser tab are closing or updating, but the navigation.type shows the same values.
Chrome displays different types of buttons when updated or closed.

- Refresh: Button confirm says: "**Refresh**"
- Close: Button confirm says: "**Leave**"

Can I identify, without bind keys event to set global variables, only with event?

Code:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  if (e.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type == 1) {
       console.log("refresh");
  } else {
       console.log("not refresh");
  }  
}
```

This is my first question here, I apologize for anything out of the question pattern.
Thank everyone;

Comment: MDN says "The PerformanceNavigation interface represents information about how the navigation _to the current document_ was done." (emphasis added).

Comment: you cant edit the default browser msg anymore. because scammer will use them if lastest browser allow this again

Comment: Thanks for answers, I dont want edit the msg, i just want to know when are refresh or close.